# Android: Manifest merger faild : Attribute application@appComponentFactory

Tags: android

I am getting the following error on compiling.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-27:19 to override.

Can anyone please help me to fix it.

#### build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//additional android libs
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
// third-party libs
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0' // butter-knife
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0' // butter-knife
implementation 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1' // registration stepper
```

#### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".RegisterTravelerActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AuthTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It is not working. giving another error `Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed` I found the reason is the `ButterKnife` library. Any idea on it?

Comment: Migrate to Android X  and add  compile option for Java 8 in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

i am facing same issue for fix that you have to check all third party lib version one on them is using android x lib. find that lib and reduce the lib version

one other way is you have to update you appcompat lib and other lib to android x lib